# How to typecast from character varying to integer in postgresql?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have one column as database_value and i want to sum it in my table and there are thousands of data and it is of character varying type.I want to typecast it to integer type but it is not giving 
me to change.

MY sql is :

```
alter table species_data alter column database_value type numeric(10,0) using database_value::numeric
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "2478a"
```

can someone say me whats the error and how to solve it?

Comment: "2478a" is not a number, how do you want to convert it? Either it's 2478 or it's hexadecimal and the value is 149386. Pick the right one and update the value in your table.

Comment: no all the datas inside the database_value are integer but the person who made database putted the column into character varying so i m getting such error while changing

Comment: Plan B: rename your column, create the column with the right type, update your table to copy and cast the strings to numbers into the new column, drop the old column.